# Upload an image to PHP with Swift 2.0

Tags: php, ios, wordpress, swift, swift2

I've searched for a long time now and nothing works out for me.
I've even tried Alamofire.
I'm trying to upload an image in an iOS App (Swift 2.0) to a Wordpress Photo-Contest plugin through PHP. The PHP script is also used for the Wordpress website to upload images.

This is the PHP:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once("../../../../../wp-load.php");

    $username = $_POST["username"];

    $m = contest_upload_photo('contest-upload-photo', 'contest_upload_photo',username_exists($username ));


function contest_upload_photo($atts, $content = null,$user_ID=null) {

//Important variables 

if ($user_ID == null){
    die(); 
}

$html = '';//Inciate output string
$koncovky = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

$number_images = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'contest_user_images', true);
if(empty($number_images)){$number_images=0;}


$error = array();
// Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content

$name = trim($_POST['photo-name']);
    /*if (empty($_POST['photo-title'])){
    $error['title'] = __('Please enter the photo title','photo-contest');
} else {
    $title = trim($_POST['photo-title']);  
}*/
//Check photo


if ($_FILES['contest-photo']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE){
    $error['photo'] = __('Please select the image','photo-contest');
} else {

  //Control upload and extension
  if ($_FILES['contest-photo']['error']) {
    $error['upload_error'] = __('Error image upload.','photo-contest');
  } 
  elseif (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['contest-photo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), $koncovky)) {
    $error['extension_error'] = __('Image must be jpg, png or gif.','photo-contest');
  } 
  elseif (!($imagesize = getimagesize($_FILES['contest-photo']['tmp_name'])) || $imagesize[2] > 3) {
    $error['type_error'] = __('Image type must be jpg, png or gif.','photo-contest');
  }   
  else {

    @$img=getimagesize($_FILES['contest-photo']['tmp_name']);

    $minimum = array('width' => '400', 'height' => '400');
    $width= $img[0];
    $height =$img[1];
      if ($width < $minimum['width'] ){
        $error['type_error'] = __('Minimum image width is 400px.','photo-contest');
      }
      elseif ($height <  $minimum['height']){
        $error['type_error'] = __('Minimum image height is 400px.','photo-contest');
      }
      $photo_limit = get_option( 'pcplugin-photo-limit', true );
      $size_maxi = $photo_limit;  
      $size = filesize($_FILES['contest-photo']['tmp_name']); 
      if($size>$size_maxi){  
        $error['size_error'] = __('File size is above allowed limitations!','photo-contest');  
}  
    }


}


if(empty($error)){
//If no exist error - create attachment post
  if(empty($_POST['photo-description'])){ 
    $description = sanitize_text_field($_POST['photo-description']);
  }else{
    $description = '';
  }

@$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($_FILES['contest-photo']['name']), null );
@$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$attachment = array(
 'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $_FILES['contest-photo']['name'] ), 
 'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
 'post_title' => $name,
 'post_content' => $description,
 'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
$attach_id = media_handle_upload( 'contest-photo', 0,$attachment );

$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $_FILES['contest-photo']['name']) );

wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

update_post_meta($attach_id,'contest-active',1);
update_post_meta($attach_id,'contest-photo-points',0);
update_post_meta($attach_id,'contest-photo-author',$user_ID);
    update_post_meta($attach_id,'post_author',$user_ID);

$number_images = $number_images+1;
update_user_meta($user_ID, 'contest_user_images', $number_images);


    $my_post = array(
  'ID'           => $attach_id,
  'post_author'   => $user_ID,
    );

    wp_update_post( $my_post );


    $image = get_post( $attach_id );

    if ($attach_id==""){
        die("306");
    }else{
        echo($attach_id); 
    }
    if ( ! $image || 'attachment' != $image->post_type || 'image/' != substr( $image->post_mime_type, 0, 6 ) )
        die( json_encode( array( 'error' => sprintf( __( 'Failed resize: %s is an invalid image ID.', 'regenerate-thumbnails' ), esc_html( $attach_id ) ) ) ) );



    $fullsizepath = get_attached_file( $image->ID );

    if ( false === $fullsizepath || ! file_exists( $fullsizepath ) )

    // @set_time_limit( 900 ); // 5 minutes per image should be PLENTY

    $metadata = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $image->ID, $fullsizepath );

    if ( is_wp_error( $metadata ) )
    if ( empty( $metadata ) )
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $image->ID, $metadata );
return $attach_id; 


}


}
    ?>
```

And this is my function in SWIFT:

```
func send()
{

    let imageData :NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(globalImage, 1.0)!;
    var request: NSMutableURLRequest?
    let HTTPMethod: String = "POST"
    let timeoutInterval: NSTimeInterval = 60
    let HTTPShouldHandleCookies: Bool = false
    let postString = "username=\(globalUsr)"

    request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "***URL TO upload.php***")!)
    request!.HTTPMethod = HTTPMethod
    request!.timeoutInterval = timeoutInterval
    request!.HTTPShouldHandleCookies = HTTPShouldHandleCookies
    request!.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


    let boundary = "----------SwIfTeRhTtPrEqUeStBoUnDaRy"
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
    request!.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
    let body = NSMutableData();


    let tempData = NSMutableData()
    let fileName = "\(globalImage.description).jpg"
    let parameterName = "contest-photo"


    let mimeType = "application/octet-stream"

    tempData.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    let fileNameContentDisposition = "photo-description=\(fileName)"
    let contentDisposition = "Content-Disposition: form-data; contest-photo=\"\(parameterName)\"; \(fileNameContentDisposition)\r\n"
    tempData.appendData(contentDisposition.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    tempData.appendData("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    tempData.appendData(imageData)
    tempData.appendData("\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    body.appendData(tempData)

    body.appendData("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    request!.setValue("\(body.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request!.HTTPBody = body

    do {
        let data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request!, returningResponse: nil)
        print("\(data)-Data")
    } catch (let vl_error) {
        print("\(vl_error)-Error")
    }


}
```

After a lot back and forth, I've messed up the code a lot and also copied some code from other people that I've found just to make it work.
I do get "<>-Data" printed out in the console.
I would appreciate any help or hint.

Comment: what is the error that you are having? are you uploading to a rest web service ?

Comment: What debugging have you done? How do you know it's not working? What do you actually get back in the response from the server (you'll need to use returningResponse rather than passing in nil to find out.) What's in the server error logs? What happens if you use an API test tool (Postman, Paw, etc.) to send an image to the page rather than Swift?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan I'm not getting any error, the file doesn't upload and therefore doesn't appear on the website.

Comment: @AlRas can you print the http response headers ?

Comment: @MattGibson I've tried a couple of different scripts and also no file is being uploaded in wordpress. There are no error messages, in the app I do get returned <>-Data. I'm programming in Swift only since a few weeks now, so I don't really know where to start. I'm thinking of deleting the whole function and creating a new one, but I don't know what else would work.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan The console prints out Optional() if I ask for the http response headers

Comment: there must be many headers. kindly check, and specially the response code

Comment: @WilliamKinaan  I'm also getting this: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fe961ec0200> { URL: url } { status code: 200, headers { "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"; Connection = close; "Content-Length" = 0; "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"; Date = "Mon, 28 Sep 2015 22:08:57 GMT"; Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT"; Pragma = "no-cache"; Server = "Apache/2.4.10"; "Set-Cookie" = "qtrans_cookie_test=1; path=/; domain=***domain***"; "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.12"; } }) I've replaced url and the domain

Comment: That means the request was successfully sent. Check please if u are getting the request body on the server. Try to print the whole request in the server. Sorry I don't have a laptop right now

Comment: @WilliamKinaan Ok, I've built in error messages in the php file. The request dies with the error message that the user_ID is null, but I'm sending the username to the php file. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @AlRas i checked your code, and indeed you are sending the username correctly but you said that you are looking for user_id not username. is that your problem? plus, are you sure that your webservice accepts the same request that you are sending from swift ? i can give you a working example for both client (swift) and server (java REST service) if you want

Comment: @WilliamKinaan I've tried another script without accessing the wordpress plugin, which works fine. Something seems to be not working with the php, because if I type in the url in my browser with ?username=admin and I print the variable $username, it's still null. I would appreciate it if you could send me the working example.

Comment: @AlRas please notice that putting the variables in the URL is not correct according to your PHP script, because `@POST['username']` means that the username is in the body of the request. I will give you a working exmaple:

Comment: @AlRas have you checked my answer please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking in comments, you needed a working example to post your username value to the server. 
This is a java REST web service:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/swiftCalculator")
public String swiftCalculator(@FormParam("x") int x, @FormParam("y") int y){
    System.out.println("x="+x);
    System.out.println("y="+y);
    return (x + y) + "";
}
```

And this is how you call it from your swift client:

```
 func testPost(sender: UIButton) {
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/iOSServer/ios/helloworld/swiftCalculator")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let d = "4"
        let data = "x=4&y=\(d)"
        request.HTTPBody = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            if let data = data{
                print("data =\(data)")
            }
            if let response = response {
                print("response = \(response)")
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Please notice that the script expects to have the values in post, so what you were doing is passing the username to the url and then ask your php script to find it in the post variables. that is why you were getting null in you php script.

In this example, i tried to **post** two variables, which are x and y from my swift client to my REST jersey web service.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted the function in swift which works fine so far now.
I only need to know how to upload a file to the php script, I've tried different approaches but it now gives me the error that the Image must be jpg, png or gif.
Username, photo name and description get accepted by the script.

```
func send()  {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "***URL***")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "username=\(globalUsr)&photo-name=\(globalImage.description)&photo-description=\(message.text)"

    let myData : NSData! = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let imageData :NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(globalImage, 1.0)!;

    let boundary = "----------SwIfTeRhTtPrEqUeStBoUnDaRy"
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
    let body = NSMutableData();

    let tempData = NSMutableData()
    let fileName = "\(globalImage.description).jpg"
    let parameterName = "contest-photo"


    let mimeType = "application/octet-stream"

    tempData.appendData(myData)
    tempData.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    let fileNameContentDisposition = "name=\(fileName)"
    let contentDisposition = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(fileName)\"; \(imageData)\r\n"
    tempData.appendData(contentDisposition.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    tempData.appendData("Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    tempData.appendData(imageData)
    tempData.appendData("\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)


    body.appendData(tempData)

    body.appendData("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    request.setValue("\(body.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.HTTPBody = body

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString!)")
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Now you have another problem, if my answer helps you please accept it, then start a new question expressing your new problem

Comment: if you post a new question, please give me the link.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan I've created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934329/swift-php-multipart-image-upload