# Upload multipart image to PHP server from iOS app

Tags: php, ios, swift, swift2, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload an image with my iOS app (Swift 2.0). The server gets the request and sends status 200, but when it comes to the file upload the image-data doesn't get uploaded. The `print_r($_FILES);` command gives me response:

```
Array
(
)
wrong format for image
```

This is the code:

```
func send()
{

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "***URL to upload.php***")!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "username=\(globalUsr)&photo-name=\(globalImage.description)&photo-description=\(message.text)"

    let myData : NSData! = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let imageData :NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(globalImage, 1.0)!;

    let boundary = "-----SwiftBoundary-----"
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
    let body = NSMutableData();

    let tempData = NSMutableData()
    let fileName = "\(globalImage.description).jpg"
    let parameterName = "contest-photo"

    tempData.appendData(myData)
    tempData.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    let fileNameContentDisposition = "name=\(parameterName)"
    let contentDisposition = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(fileName)\"; \(fileNameContentDisposition)\r\n"
    tempData.appendData(contentDisposition.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    tempData.appendData("Content-Type: \(contentType)\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    tempData.appendData(imageData)
    tempData.appendData("\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)


    body.appendData(tempData)

    body.appendData("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    request.setValue("\(body.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.HTTPBody = body


    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString!)")
    }
    task.resume()


}
```

The PHP code is:

```
<?php

// Load Wordpress
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once("../../../../../wp-load.php");

    $username = $_POST["username"];

    $m = contest_upload_photo('contest-upload-photo','contest_upload_photo',username_exists($username ));




function contest_upload_photo($atts, $content = null,$user_ID=null) {

//Important variables 
if ($user_ID == null){
    die(json_encode("There is no user.")); 
}

$html = '';//Inciate output string
$koncovky = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

$number_images = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'contest_user_images', true);
if(empty($number_images)){$number_images=0;}


$error = array();
// Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content

$name = trim($_POST['photo-name']);
    /*if (empty($_POST['photo-title'])){
    $error['title'] = __('Please enter the photo title','photo-contest');
} else {
    $title = trim($_POST['photo-title']);  
}*/


//Check photo
if ($_FILES['contest-photo']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE){
    $error['photo'] = __('Please select the image','photo-contest');
    die("no photo selected");
} else {

  //Control upload and extension
  if ($_FILES['contest-photo']['error']) {
    $error['upload_error'] = __('Error image upload.','photo-contest');
    die("Image upload error");
  } 
  elseif (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['contest-photo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), $koncovky)) {
    $error['extension_error'] = __('Image must be jpg, png or gif.','photo-contest');
    print($koncovky);
    print_r($_FILES);
    die("wrong format for image");
  } 
  elseif (!($imagesize = getimagesize($_FILES['contest-photo']['tmp_name'])) || $imagesize[2] > 3) {
    $error['type_error'] = __('Image type must be jpg, png or gif.','photo-contest');
    die("image too big");
  }   
  else {

    @$img=getimagesize($_FILES['contest-photo']['tmp_name']);

    $minimum = array('width' => '400', 'height' => '400');
    $width= $img[0];
    $height =$img[1];
      if ($width < $minimum['width'] ){
        $error['type_error'] = __('Minimum image width is 400px.','photo-contest');
        die("width is too small");
      }
      elseif ($height <  $minimum['height']){
        $error['type_error'] = __('Minimum image height is 400px.','photo-contest');
        die("height is too small");
      }
      $photo_limit = get_option( 'pcplugin-photo-limit', true );
      $size_maxi = $photo_limit;  
      $size = filesize($_FILES['contest-photo']['tmp_name']); 
      if($size>$size_maxi){  
        $error['size_error'] = __('File size is above allowed limitations!','photo-contest'); 
        die("file is too big"); 
}  
    }


}


if(empty($error)){
//If no exist error - create attachment post
  if(empty($_POST['photo-description'])){ 
    $description = sanitize_text_field($_POST['photo-description']);
  }else{
    $description = '';
  }

@$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($_FILES['contest-photo']['name']), null );
@$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$attachment = array(
 'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $_FILES['contest-photo']['name'] ), 
 'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
 'post_title' => $name,
 'post_content' => $description,
 'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
$attach_id = media_handle_upload( 'contest-photo', 0,$attachment );

$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $_FILES['contest-photo']['name']) );

wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

update_post_meta($attach_id,'contest-active',1);
update_post_meta($attach_id,'contest-photo-points',0);
update_post_meta($attach_id,'contest-photo-author',$user_ID);
    update_post_meta($attach_id,'post_author',$user_ID);

$number_images = $number_images+1;
update_user_meta($user_ID, 'contest_user_images', $number_images);


    $my_post = array(
  'ID'           => $attach_id,
  'post_author'   => $user_ID,
    );

    wp_update_post( $my_post );


    $image = get_post( $attach_id );

    if ($attach_id==""){
        die("306");
    }else{
        echo($attach_id); 
    }
    if ( ! $image || 'attachment' != $image->post_type || 'image/' != substr( $image->post_mime_type, 0, 6 ) )
        die( json_encode( array( 'error' => sprintf( __( 'Failed resize: %s is an invalid image ID.', 'regenerate-thumbnails' ), esc_html( $attach_id ) ) ) ) );



    $fullsizepath = get_attached_file( $image->ID );

    if ( false === $fullsizepath || ! file_exists( $fullsizepath ) )

    // @set_time_limit( 900 ); // 5 minutes per image should be PLENTY

    $metadata = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $image->ID, $fullsizepath );

    if ( is_wp_error( $metadata ) )
    if ( empty( $metadata ) )
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $image->ID, $metadata );
return $attach_id; 


}


}
    ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

If I try it without:

```
request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

I get:

```
data =<22546865 72652069 73206e6f 20757365 722e22>
response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fcd7e184980> { URL: http://www.clip2gether.com/mobile/app/v1/iOS/upload/upload.php } { status code: 200, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
Connection = close;
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Sun, 04 Oct 2015 20:39:26 GMT";
Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = "Apache/2.4.10";
"Set-Cookie" = "qtrans_cookie_test=1; path=/; domain=www.clip2gether.com";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.12";
} }
```

And if I try it with the line:

```
request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

data =<41727261 79417272 61790a28 0a290a77 726f6e67 20666f72 6d617420 666f7220 696d6167 65>
response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fdd22f3e660> { URL: http://www.clip2gether.com/mobile/app/v1/iOS/upload/upload.php } { status code: 200, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
Connection = close;
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Sun, 04 Oct 2015 20:46:19 GMT";
Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = "Apache/2.4.10";
"Set-Cookie" = "qtrans_cookie_test=1; path=/; domain=www.clip2gether.com";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.12";
} }
```

So basically I'm getting the same response with setting the value contentType, as hex-code:

```
There is no user
```

and without setting it

```
ArrayArray
(
)
wrong format for image
```

Comment: to start debug the problem, first please add a content type to our http request as this: `request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`

Comment: @WilliamKinaan If I add the content-type I get the response "There is no user", which means the user_id = null and the username is not sent to the PHP

Comment: Please execute this request `let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
 let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            if let data = data{
                print("data =\(data)")
            }
            if let response = response {
                print("response = \(response)")
            }
        })
        task.resume()` and tell me what will be written

Comment: @WilliamKinaan I had to post it as answer, the code was too long

Comment: in your php script, you are receiving the username in $username variable not in $user_id variable, kindly print the $username variable and tell me the result

Comment: please delete your answer, and add it as an update to your question.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan Thanks for the advise. I'm new to stackoverflow. I've printed the `$username` and it is null, but the `user_ID` holds the correct wordpress `user_ID` of the wordpress user that I've sent to the script. Otherwise it wouldn't get to the point where it checks for the `$_FILE`

Comment: i don't know what is happing on the code. sorry i tried my best to help you. my advice is to simplify the problem. try first to send a post value to the server, then try to post an image (or a file), then try to add a multipart request ....

Comment: @WilliamKinaan Sending a post value to the server works fine (user authentication), sending and uploading a file with a more simpler php form works too, but I want to upload the file into the wordpress photo contest plugin, where the authentication works too but the file transfer somehow doesn't work correctly. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `body` data is wrong formatted for a `multipart/form-data` enctype. Assuming that you want to POST the following fields:

- `username` a text field
- `photo-name` a text field
- `photo-description` a text field
- `contest-photo` a file field(will contain image's binary data)

Your body should look like:

```
--SwiftBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

my username value
--SwiftBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo-name"

my photo-name value
--SwiftBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo-description"

my photo-description value
--SwiftBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="contest-photo"; filename="myfile.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

...my image binary data...
--SwiftBoundary--
```

You also will have to set the following headers on request:

- `Content-Length` to the length of body
- and `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=SwiftBoundary`, here is important that the `boundary` string matches the one used in body

If you manage to update your request to look like above, you will find your image data under `$_FILES['contest-photo']`

Your `send` function should look something like this:

```
func send()
{
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "***URL to upload.php***")!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let imageData :NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(globalImage, 1.0)!;

    let boundary = "SwiftBoundary"
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
    let fileName = "\(globalImage.description).jpg"
    let parameterName = "contest-photo"

    let body = NSMutableData()

    body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("\(globalUsr)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo-name\"\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("\(globalImage.description)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo-description\"\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("\(message.text)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(parameterName)\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    body.appendData(imageData)
    body.appendData("\r\n--\(boundary)--".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("\(body.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.HTTPBody = body


    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString!)")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I put the boundary before the username, the script doesn't get the username and stops at the `if user_ID == nil`. Also if I do `request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")` the request get's stuck at the error message `There is no user`.

Comment: @AlRas i added a code snippet for how your `send` function should look like.

Comment: Thanks for writing down the code snippet. I had to encode the strings, because I received the error message `Cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type 'NSData`, so I added `.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!` to every string, but I still get the response `There is no user`. So the request doesn't pass over the username. In my code before it got past the username und `user_ID`, which were correct when I printed them, but it told me the image has the wrong format. Do you have any other ideas why this is not working?

Comment: @AlRas hmm, in your php file, if you do `var_dump($_POST, $_FILES)` what do you see?

Comment: I'm not able to do a `var_dump($_POST, $_FILES)`, because wherever I put it, I get a Parse error, syntax error in the line below.

Comment: @AlRas in php `;` at the end of instruction is mandatory, so it should be `var_dump($_POST, $_FILES);`

Comment: It prints `array(227) {
  ["username"]=>
  string(6) "admin5"
  ["photo-name"]=>
  string(15) "140375729961888"
  ["photo-description"]=>
  string(260) "-------SwiftBoundary-----
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"140375729961888.jpg\"; name=photo-name
Content-Type: image/jpeg; boundary=-----SwiftBoundary-----` and after that there is a long hex-code with the image data

Comment: Oh and I just saw it prints at the end `
-------SwiftBoundary-------
"
  }
}
array(0) {
}
wrong format for image`

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2 here's the official documentation for how an multipart/form-data request should look like

Comment: @AlRas sry, just noticed an error in the way I was generating the boundary; i fixed that now in the code, it should work properly now. The idea is that for multipart/form-data you have to provide a boundary through header like: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MyCustomBoundary`, and then you use that boundary to delimit your data fields like: `--MyCustomBoundary`(it starts with `--`), and your request should end like `--MyCustomBoundary--`

Comment: I only need to change `body.length` to `\(body.length)`, but the code works now. Thanks a lot, you were a great help.

Comment: i tried a lot of examples and code from SO and github, but only this works, thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for hours and finally pieced this working code together using mostly info from this page.

Here's how you can upload an image together with a text parameter to a PHP script and save the image on the server.

```
// PHP SCRIPT (the content of upload.php)
<?php
$image = $_FILES['image-upload']['tmp_name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$filename = "upload_" . date("ymd_at_H_i_s", time()) . ".jpg";
if (move_uploaded_file($image, $filename)) {
    echo "Image upload for user ".$username." Success"; // this will show up in XCode output
} else {
    echo "Image upload for user ".$username."  Failed"; // this will show up in XCode output
}
?>




// SWIFT 2.3 IMAGE UPLOAD FUNCTION 
let uploadPHPURL = "http://somehost.com/uploads/upload.php"
func uploadImage(image:UIImage?, userName:String)
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: self.uploadPHPURL)!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        //let image = self.imageView.image
        let imageData :NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.3)!

        let boundary = "--- unique boundary string ---"
        let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
        let fileName = "image.jpg"
        let parameterName = "image-upload"

        let body = NSMutableData()


        // duplicate this if you need to send more parameters to the php script
        body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("\(userName)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



        // this is the file parameter
        body.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(parameterName)\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(imageData)
        body.appendData("\r\n--\(boundary)--".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

        request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("\(body.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.HTTPBody = body


        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("imageUpload responseString: \(responseString!)")
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```